# How to convert Java annotation to Go code?

Tags: java, go

I'm changing my Java project to Go language. I'm using a Java *annotation* and want to convert it into Go code. I want to know the best data structure in Go to convert this annotation.

My code is as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func getBody(method string, Id string, auth string, body []byte,timeStamp int64) ([]byte, error) {

    url := "****************"+Id+"***********"+strconv.FormatInt(timeStamp,10)
    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, bytes.NewReader(body))

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var header = make(map[string]string,2)
    header["Accept"]="*******************"
    header["Authorization"]=auth
    
    for key, value := range header {
        req.Header.Add(key, value)
    }

    res, err := client.Do(req)
    defer res.Body.Close()

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var bodyBytes []byte

    if res.StatusCode == 200 {
        bodyBytes, err = ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    } else if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    } else {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("The remote end did not return a HTTP 200 (OK) response.")
    }

    return bodyBytes, nil

}

func main() {
    
    method := "GET"
    auth:="************"
    var timeStamp int64 = 1441689793403
    Id:="***********"
    fmt.Println(timeStamp)
    var cs int64 = time.Now().UnixNano()/1000000
    for{
        cs = time.Now().UnixNano()/1000000
        bodyBytes, err := getBody(method, Id, auth, nil,timeStamp)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Errorf("unable to retrieve the response body from the Glance API server: %v", err)
        }
        
        var obj []interface{}
        err = json.Unmarshal(bodyBytes, &obj)
        
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Errorf("unable to parse the JSON response:", err)
        }

        for i,_:=range obj{
            m := obj[i].(map[string]interface{})
            fmt.Println(m["text"])

         /* @OnKeyWord("hi")
          public void HelloWorld(TeamchatAPI api) {
          System.out.println("Hello word");
                );  */


        }
        
        timeStamp = cs
    }
}
```

I want to convert the commented Java code into Go code.

Alternatively you can take your own example to explain, if you want.

Comment: This is not how you should approach the problem. You should not do "mirror" translation but rather "functional" translation. Annotations in Java attach meta information to different source code elements. But by themselves they worth nothing if there isn't a code or framework that processes them and does different things based on that. What you should discover is what your Java libraries/frameworks will do with the method that is annotated with `@OnKeyWord` and try to implement that functionality in Go.

Comment: but, if golang can still add 'tag' to struct and func, would be great.

Comment: **icza** you are right. I can implement @OnKeyWord functionality with _if_ statement but I was not feeling that this is the good approach. I wanted to know if there is any better method I can use for this.

Answer (score 2):

After you have done the translation as @icza explained, you wish probably to move the functionality to a middleware ([example](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/making-and-using-middleware)) that gets run for all your requests. That way you can add the assisting logic (the "if" part) out of your business methods.

There is also no need to implement middlewares for HTTP frameworks yourself. Most web frameworks [include](http://beego.me/docs/mvc/controller/filter.md) one by [default](https://revel.github.io/manual/filters.html).

Comment: Yes, but with a caveat. The middleware/framework approach should only be taken after you have actually justified that it gives you real benefits over simpler solutions (and have tried them in practice).